# NodeJS responded MySQL timezone is different when I fetch directly from MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, timezone

When I request MySQL directly, I get back date in UTC (I set UTC in MySQL server), but with NodeJS I get UTC+2 local time zone data, why? How can I set NodeJS to get UTC?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I have added timezone in index.js when initializing mysql connection

```
var db_config = {
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'xxx',
  password : '',
  database : 'xxx',
  timezone: 'utc'  //<-here this line was missing
};
```

Comment: unfortınately this does not fix the problem for me, any other answers?

Comment: Based on actual doc: 'timezone' can be 'local', 'Z', or an offset in the form +HH:MM or -HH:MM. (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options) but in my case this also does not fix the problem (setted 'Z')

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Fixed my issue here!

Answer (score 19):

Although this is an old question, I had a similar problem and adding the config `timezone: 'utc'` did not solve the problem (it get worse).

The solution I finally used is to add the config `dateStrings : true` such that I have a raw string date and mysql module does not do itself the conversion to a javascript date.

Then I use moment.utc(thedatestring) to obtain a suitable javascript object (in the database, I save all dates as UTC in DATETIME columns, independently of the configuration of the host). Using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is already answered, and old, but if you are using mysql2 library and having problems setting the timezone to UTC, you can do it using "Z" timezone. Z stands for Zulu, [explanation from here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z)

```
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'test',
  password: 'mypass',
  timezone: 'Z',
})
```

Setting this timezone configuration means that every Date (Javascript Date object) will be translated TO utc when sent to database and FROM utc when it comes from the database. [Here is the implementation, from mysql2 GitHub repository](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/pull/996/files).

Answer (score 5):

after falling to that problem again and again i've found the desired solution.

My `nodeJS` app fetching data from `mySQL` db via `Sequelize` ORM.

Make sure the timezone is the same everywhere.

`config.js`:

```
const timezone = 'UTC'
process.env.TZ = timezone
```

`sequelize_config.js`:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, 
  options: {
    host,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port,

    dialectOptions: {
       /* useUTC: true, **deprecated** */ 
       timezone: 'utc'
    },
  }
}
```

Hope it will save someone's time from falling to this loop... :)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the timezone value to "UTC+0", that worked for me.

Comment: Awesome. Worked for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the dateStrings property to DATETIME.

dateStrings: Force date types (TIMESTAMP, DATETIME, DATE) to be returned as strings rather then inflated into JavaScript Date objects. (Default: false)

Refer: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but it can be resolved setting the TZ environment variable to 'UTC+0'. There are several ways to achieve that, a few of them are:

- In bash:

  - `$ TZ='UTC+0' node index.js`
- Inside the code:

  - `process.env.TZ = "UTC+0"`
- In Visual Code alter the `launch.json` configuration file. E.g:

```json
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasename}",
        "env": {"TZ": "UTC+0"}  // <-- ADD THIS
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a function for automatically resolving the timezone of the server it's being used from for mysql / mariadb, and made it into a tiny package for anyone interested: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-tz

`yarn add mysql-tz`

```
import mariadb, { PoolConnection } from "mariadb";
import mysqlTz from "mysql-tz";

const maria_pool = mariadb.createPool({
  database: "SomeDatabase",
  user: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  timezone: mysqlTz(),
  connectionLimit: 25
});
```

for e.g., i'm on the east-coast of north america so calling "mysqlTz" would return "GMT-0400"