# node mysql not recognizing 6th July date

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am running mysql from node using [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

I have observed a strange behavior where data from 6th July is not recognized.

The following is the code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var dbconn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    user: 'xxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxxx'
        });
connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    queryString = "select max(createdon) max_date from gate";


DBSelect(dbconn, queryString, [], function (success, msgObj) {
console.log(' ');

    console.log('// dbconn.config.dateStrings', dbconn.config.dateStrings);
    console.log('msgObj', msgObj.results[0].max_date);

    dbconn.config.dateStrings = true;
    console.log(' ');

    DBSelect(dbconn, queryString, [], function (success, msgObj) {
        console.log('// dbconn.config.dateStrings', dbconn.config.dateStrings);
        console.log('msgObj', msgObj.results[0].max_date);
    })

})


});


function DBSelect(dbObject, queryString, values, callback) {
    dbObject.query({
        sql: queryString,
        timeout: 40000, // 40s
    },
        values,
        function (error, results, fields) {

            if (error !== null) {
                callback(false, error);
            }
            else {
                callback(true, {
                    results: results,
                    fields: fields
                });
            }
        }
    )
}
```

and this is the output i get

```
// dbconn.config.dateStrings false
msgObj 2018-07-05T13:48:58.000Z

// dbconn.config.dateStrings true
msgObj 2018-07-05 19:18:58
```

But when i execute the same query from Navicat (mysql client similar to MySQL Workbench) i get proper response

[image]

Unable to identify the issue, please suggest.

Comment: It seems most likely that you aren't actually querying the same database/table.

Comment: :)

that is not the case Eddie. i have checked

Comment: The thing is, you aren't having a timezone issue or some kind of data type conversion issue, it doesn't seem.  Why doesn't the word 'result' appear in your output, it seems from your code that should.

Comment: Nah!! Thats due to some inline changes i have done after pasting the code in SO

Comment: Looks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571110/nodejs-responded-mysql-timezone-is-different-when-i-fetch-directly-from-mysql related to this question

Comment: thanks, adding the time zone has removed the inconsistency between `dateStrings` true and false. But the actual problem persists... in node it still shows 5th July is the max created date and navicat shows 6th july.

Comment: can you show the SHOW CREATE TABLE gate.

Comment: I can. But for your info 'gate'  table is just for example. I have same problem for other tables also