# Datetime changing on JSON response

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, json

I am selecting start and end date of a project from `project_stage` named table.

**Here is the table elements**

```
stage_start_date    stage_end_date       planned_start_date   planned_end_date
2019-01-28 10:12:01  2020-12-08 09:05:28 2019-01-12 01:01:00  2020-12-01 00:00:00
```

Here datatype is `DATETIME`

**Here is the code**

```
SELECT ps.stage_start_date AS actual_start_date, 
       ps.stage_end_date AS actual_end_date, 
       ps.stage_planned_start_date AS planned_start_date, 
       ps.stage_planned_end_date AS planned_end_date 
FROM project_stage AS ps 
JOIN map_project_user AS mpu ON mpu.user_id = 22 AND mpu.project_id = 1 AND mpu.tenant_id = ps.tenant_id AND ps.project_id = mpu.project_id;
```

**Result on JSON response**

```
{
   "actual_start_date": "2019-01-28T04:42:01.000Z",
   "actual_end_date": "2020-12-08T03:35:28.000Z",
   "planned_start_date": "2019-01-11T19:31:00.000Z",
   "planned_end_date": "2020-11-30T18:30:00.000Z"
}
```

Here date time is changing its not the actual datetime which is in the table,why the date is changing on result.Here is the expected output

**Expected Result**

```
{
   "actual_start_date": "2019-01-28 10:12:01",
   "actual_end_date": "2020-12-08 09:05:28",
   "planned_start_date": "2019-01-12 01:01:00",
   "planned_end_date": "2020-12-01 00:00:00"
}
```

MYSQL DATATYPE is `DATETIME`. Data base `timezone` is in `UTC` and  System `timezone` is also showing `UTC`, How can I covert this datetime corresponding to `timezone` of users system

Comment: What is transforming the query results to json?

Comment: Seems to be timezone issue. Like UTC vs IST (+5:30)

Comment: Timezones, your SQL server must be in a different timezone. You should get the timezone of that server and account for it in your code, or change the timezone

Comment: What's the DATATYPE in MySQL?  `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` work differently.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`  What is the timezone for your computer?  For the server?

Comment: MYSQL DATATYPE is `DATETIME`. Timezone is in `UTC` System timezone is also showing `UTC`

Comment: I need to get the timezone as `IST` on my response, how to resolve this issue in query

Comment: Actually timezone is encoded in the json in the last bit `000Z`. So, the application loading the json can just covet it to any required time zone.

Comment: You might want to check your node.js conection to mysql. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571110/nodejs-responded-mysql-timezone-is-different-when-i-fetch-directly-from-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the data examples, the Timezone issue appears to be in the code that converts the SQL result to JSON. Since the time difference between the database and the JSON is -05:30, it seems that the "JSON transformer" assumes that the result of the SQL query is IST (UTC +05: 30) and converts the time to UTC (subtracts 5:30).

The correct fix should be done in the "JSON transformer". However, if the requirement is to achieve the "corrected date" by modifying the SQL query, you can use the `CONVERT_TZ (dt, from_tz, to_tz)` function. This adds +5:30 and "JSON transformer" subtracts 5:30 later resulting the time being unchanged.

Something like that:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(ps.stage_start_date, '+00:00', '+05:30'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") AS actual_start_date, 
       DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(ps.stage_end_date, '+00:00', '+05:30'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") AS actual_end_date, 
       DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(ps.stage_planned_start_date, '+00:00', '+05:30'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") AS planned_start_date, 
       DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(ps.stage_planned_end_date, '+00:00', '+05:30'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") AS planned_end_date 
FROM project_stage AS ps 
JOIN map_project_user AS mpu ON mpu.user_id = 22 
                             AND mpu.project_id = 1
                             AND mpu.tenant_id = ps.tenant_id
                             AND ps.project_id = mpu.project_id;
```

Edit: Another option: simply add +5:30 to the dates:

```
SELECT ps.stage_start_date + interval 5 hour + 30 minute AS actual_start_date, 
       ps.stage_end_date + interval 5 hour + 30 minute AS actual_end_date, 
       ps.stage_planned_start_date + interval 5 hour + 30 minute AS planned_start_date, 
       ps.stage_planned_end_date + interval 5 hour + 30 minute AS planned_end_date 
FROM project_stage AS ps 
JOIN map_project_user AS mpu ON mpu.user_id = 22 
                             AND mpu.project_id = 1
                             AND mpu.tenant_id = ps.tenant_id
                             AND ps.project_id = mpu.project_id;
```

Comment: Their is no change on output ,it gives same output :`{"actual_start_date": "2019-01-28T10:12:01.000Z"}`

Comment: Added 2nd option to answer  `stage_start_date + interval 5 hour + 30 minute`

Comment: 2nd option is also not giving the expected result , here is the op get from 2nd option `20201201050030`

Comment: @RahmanHaroon, the time output in your first comment is the same as your expected result for stage_start_date: **10:12:01**

Comment: This is the result `T10:12:01.000Z`, But I just need to get `10:12:01` @TaaviTitsu

Comment: Added `date_fromat()` to the first sql.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend changes the time format. Check you API which connects to the database.